# DropDownList refresh on second attempt in gridview asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am facing a problem while adding new records by selecting drop down items. Basically it is a gridview in which I select AddressType, Country then City then CityArea and so on using dropdown. In first attempt it is working fine, but on second attempt when I select Country it reset the selected item.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoTtU.jpg

as you can see in the above picture, on second attempt I am going to select Country. As soon as I select the Country it refresh. Look in the below picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObeT5.jpg

Please help me to find the solution.
Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country" HeaderStyle-Width="14%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Country.Description") %>'
                                runat="server">   </asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UPCountry">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountryNew" DataSourceID="odsCountry" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountryNew_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                    AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Id" CssClass="myWidth-7" />
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCountryNew" />
                            </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" DataSourceID="odsCountry" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.CountryId") %>'
                                DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Id" CssClass="myWidth-6" ValidationGroup="EditAddressGroup" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

C#:

```
protected void ddlCountryNew_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddlCountryNew = (DropDownList)sender;
        hdnCountryId.Value = ddlCountryNew.SelectedItem.Value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the dropdownlist to trigger Ajax call *without refreshing the page*

Set `EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"` like below

```
<Triggers> 
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCountryNew" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" /> 
</Triggers>
```

Have a keen look over through the [Update Panel MSDN document with example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Nope.. Still getting issue.